# Glyphs not showing in all my browsers

Tags: html, icons

Somehow the glyphs seem to be missing. Any solution for this?

Here are the screenshots from http://www.templatemonster.com/ using IE, firefox and chrome browsers.

http://wthdesign.net/Glyphs-not-showing.jpg

Comment: Please provide more detail of what we're looking at here. Are those just screenshots of a default template? Did you modify it somehow? A relevant code sample would be helpful.

Comment: @mikhail no I didn't modify it, the screenshots were taken directly from the templatemonster website using my pc's browsers, and all the glyphs don't seem to show. However when I view the site using my laptop all the glyphs are showing as usual. Is there something wrong with my computer setting? Also other websites that use glyphs don't seem to show as well, so basically my pc just doesn't seem to display html glyphs at all....